# macOS sierra and Selenium Edge

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, nightwatch.js

I am using a MacBook with Sierra 10.12.1 and Selenium 3.0.1 and Nightwatchjs.

Chrome works, Firefox works, Safari kinda works (won´t find CSS Elements) but IE is not doing a thing.

I downloaded the Webdriver from here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/ but it is not overcoming this

```
Starting selenium server...
```

In my test_settings I have:

```
"edge" : {
    "selenium_port"  : 4444,
      "selenium_host"  : "localhost",
      "silent": true,      
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
        "javascriptEnabled" : true
              }
    }
```

and my selenium settings are:

```
"selenium" : {
    "start_process" : true,
    "server_path" : "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar",
    "log_path" : "",
    "port" : 4444,
    "cli_args" : {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "/Users/MacBook/node_modules/chromedriver/bin/chromedriver",
      "webdriver.gecko.driver" : "/Users/MacBook/webdriver/geckodriver",
      "webdriver.firefox.profile" : "nightwatch",
      "webdriver.edge.driver" : "/Users/MacBook/webdriver/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser needs to be installed on your system in order to run it. Do you somehow have IE/Edge installed on your macbook?

Comment: not except the Webdriver. I guess I can only achieve that with a VM on mac OS right? How can I link it there anyways?

Comment: If you put a VM on macOS running Windows then you could do it, but you'd have to either run the VM as a grid node and still have the webdriver instance on the VM or run everything on the VM itself. One thing is for sure though, you need to have the browser available to run and not just the webdriver